# Insert only date into table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called attendance and I need to add field called ScanDate which will hold the current date of scan , in other word it will pick up date of server or machine. I use following line of sql command however im getting error
Can anyone can tell how to fix it or is there any other way to insert current date

```
ALTER TABLE `attendance`  ADD `ScanDate` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE ;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Those dreaded backticks look like MySQL?

Comment: DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE NOT NULL

Comment: That's not a DBMS, that's a _frontend_ for MySQL

Answer (score 0):

For SQL SERVER

```
ALTER TABLE attendance ADD ScanDate NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

For MySQL, you can use the timestamp column and this date will update if there is any changes on the row

```
ALTER TABLE `attendance ` ADD `ScanDate` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

Comment: ALTER TABLE `attendance ` ADD `ScanDate` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ; Works , but it gives me time as well ,, i need only the date (like yyyy-mm-dd) ,

Comment: Why the SQL Server answer? The question is clearly tagged with MySQL.

Comment: The question was not tagged with mysql when I first saw it, it was edited later @jarlh

Comment: @MarioBrave Try this as well  "ALTER TABLE `attendance`  ADD `ScanDate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURDATE() ;"

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
ALTER TABLE attendance ADD ScanDate NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSDATE();
```

Comment: Still getting error           #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSDATE()' at line 1

Comment: I'd try default before not null, as in ANSI SQL.

Comment: that did not helped :(

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) -- dd/MM/yyyy format
```

This query should work in SQL Server, not sure the exact syntax in MySQL, but the difference should not be that big. But you get the idea.

CONVERT can also be replaced with CAST

Comment: MySQL is very different from MS SQL Server (and both are far from ANSI SQL) when it comes to date/time...